# How can I start a clickonce application with the visual studio debugger?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, clickonce

I'm using visual studio 2012.

I have a click once application that crashes on startup so I can't **attach** the the debugger to it after it starts running.

I'd like to be able to add the path to an executable which will start the clickonce app in the form below but I can't figure out the path of the executable to use. I'm in doubt there is actually an executable anywhere that's not wrapped up in some XML envelope.

[image]

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I found the application exe at

C:\Users\phelan\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\37D5YP82.7PX\55C1R4CW.6R2\wein..tion_83d38a504d20cfb6_0001.0001_e7ff4343c37b1b52\weingartner.weinCad.master.exe

I wish there was an easier way to find this other than searching through a set of obfuscated directories.

Comment: Just to note that if you start the executable directly the framework will not initialise any of the ClickOnce APIs.

Answer (score 0):

Normally it would have been quite easy if your app were not crashing.

Go to task manager right click on the relevant process and select "open file location". Just in case you need to do it again for a different issue.